# sum all double with same date in List of Tuples (SCALA)

Tags: list, scala, tuples

I have the following list:

```
val bought = List(("ta",5.5,"1/09/21"),("ta",50.5,"2/09/20"),("xa",60.38,"1/09/21"),...)
```

I want to implement a function in Scala that returns a list of tuples, type List[(String,Double)], being String the date and Double the sum of money spent on that day.

My idea was to obtain the set of dates

```
val x = bought.map(_._3).toSet
```

and then use a for-comprehension structure to sum the value of each tuple if they have the same date, but my tries have been in vain.

Please, it should be scala like, not imperative style.

Any hint?

Comment: `bought.groupMapReduce(_._3)(_._2)(_+_).toList` (Scala 2.13.x)

Answer (score 1):

I think a 'Scala'  way to solve your problem is:

- from your list, create a Map where the key is the date and the value is the list of bought things
- sum all the money for each day

In Scala, it can be done with `groupBy` and `mapValues`:

```scala
bought.groupBy(_._3)
  .view
  .mapValues(values => values.map(_._2).sum)
  .toList
```

Comment: `.mapValues()` has been deprecated since 2.13.0.

Comment: view.mapValues() then?

Comment: Ops, yes I think that view.mapValues() should be correct. What do you think @jwvh?

Comment: [Scaladocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/Map.html#mapValues[W](f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.MapView[K,W]) _does_ recommend the rather unwieldy `.view.mapValues(...).toMap` alternative. I prefer the direct approach: `.map{case(k,v) => (k,...)}`. If you don't want to use the `groupMapReduce()` solution then either of these should work.